# How to show that $\pi \cot \pi \tau = \pi i - 2 \pi i \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q^m$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

How to show that $\pi \cot \pi \tau = \pi i - 2 \pi i \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q^m$? Here $\tau$ is a complex number, $q=e^{2 \pi i \tau}$. I try to use $\cot \pi \tau = \frac{\cos \pi \tau}{\sin \pi \tau}$ and $\sin \pi \tau = \frac{e^{\pi \tau i} - e^{-\pi \tau i}}{2i}$, $\cos \pi \tau = \frac{e^{\pi \tau i} + e^{-\pi \tau i}}{2}$. But I could not obtain the formula. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried working with the right-hand side to meet somewhere in the middle?

Comment: In particular, did you notice the right side is a geometric series?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you very much. I know how to prove this now.

Comment: @anon, thank you very much. I know how to prove this now.

Comment: Good. Write it up, and post it as an answer --- this is encouraged on this site. Then, later, you can accept this answer. Helps keep the Unanswered Questions list trim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$
\pi i - 2 \pi i \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q^m = \pi i - 2\pi i(\frac{1}{1-q}-1) \\
= \pi i - 2 \pi i (\frac{-q}{1-q}) = \pi i \frac{1+q}{1-q} \\
=  \pi i \frac{1+e^{2\pi i \tau}}{1-e^{2\pi i \tau}} = \pi \cot\pi \tau.
$$